# Capture a screenshot of XDM login screen?

Tags: freebsd, screenshot, login-manager, xdm

I would like to screenshot my XDM login screen on FreeBSD-CURRENT. It’s currently configured on ttyv8.

## What I’ve tried:

I have tried `xwd` with various options from ttyv1, but it reports is cannot open the display.

I’ve had a crack at configuring xdmcp to screenshot from my Mac via X11 forwarding, but the background does not appear.
The background is presented using `qiv` and is configured in Xsetup_*n*.

Having initially SSH’d onto the FreeBSD laptop with X forwarding enabled, the value of my DISPLAY variable was :10.0. I created an Xsetup_10 file (a straight copy from the Xsetup_0 file that works fine locally) and added the following line to `/usr/local/lib/X11/xdm/xdm-config`

```
DisplayManager._10.setup:  /usr/local/lib/X11/xdm/Xsetup_10
```

But this still didn’t work.

## Question:

How can I screenshot my XDM login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to /etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup:

```
sleep 2 && import -w root /tmp/xdm.jpg &
```

It's will take screenshot through two seconds when xdm started and will place it to /tmp folder.